# Multilevel bill-of-material through XSLT recursion

Tags: xslt

I am new to XSLT and I'm having a difficult time identifying a solution to the following problem.

I'm attempting to output an indented bill-of-material (BOM) of Items, along with an added sequence ID, from an XML file based on the IPC-257x standard.  Within the source XML file, there is a single `<Item>` element that's defined with the attribute/value `isTopLevel="Yes"`.  It's this element which defines the top-level Item of the overall BOM structure.  The next level of the BOM structure is defined under this Item's `<BillOfMaterial>` child element.  Each of the child elements themselves may have their own BOM structure, which is defined under siblings of its `<Item>` ancestor.  Moreover, each of those child elements may have their own BOM structure, which again are siblings of their `<Item>` ancestors.

I've attempted (without success) many different solutions, starting out with embedding multiple `<xsl:for-each>` statements together before realizing this likely isn't a best-practice.  Subsequently, I attempted to define multiple `<xsl:templates>`; however, this is where it became difficult to understand, primarily with the use of multiple templates for the same node and the thought of needing to use `<xsl:param>`s to define filtering.

Instead of further confusing myself, I'm hoping someone can help by provided a best-practice recommendation or solution to this problem.  I'm fairly confident recursive iteration is required, but not sure how to get there.

Thanks in advance for any help!

XML Source (abbreviated version of the much larger original):

```
<ProductDataeXchangePackage>
    <Items>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="0115020040" description="STL, SH 14GA CR">
            <BillOfMaterial>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="8151400002" itemQuantity=".0001" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="0" />
            </BillOfMaterial>
        </Item>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="3070001100" description="NUT, STD HEX M10-1.5 (SST)">
            <Attachments>
                <Attachment fileIdentifier="124559464" fileSize="52212"/>
                <Attachment fileIdentifier="124559465" fileSize="411068"/>
                <Attachment fileIdentifier="124559462" fileSize="32603"/>
            </Attachments>
        </Item>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="3070007006" description="WELDNUT, M6-1.0 (SST)"/>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="3070028000" description="WELDNUT, M5 X 0.8 (SST)"/>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="3070031000" description="WELDNUT, M12-1.75-6H (STEEL)"/>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="3110011100" description="WASHER, FLAT M10 SST (DIN125)"/>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="3110011120" description="WASHER, FLAT M12 SST (DIN125)"/>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="3150021100" description="LOCKWASHER, SPLIT M10 SST (DIN127)"/>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="3203271000" description="BOLT, CARRIAGE, M10-1.5 X 40MM"/>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="8151400002" description="SPEC, SHIPPING">
            <Attachments>
                <Attachment fileIdentifier="118969381" fileSize="399829"/>
            </Attachments>
        </Item>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="8172418068" description="SPEC,APPROVED ALT MATERIAL">
            <Attachments>
                <Attachment fileIdentifier="138337862" fileSize="145480"/>
                <Attachment fileIdentifier="138337863" fileSize="38243"/>
                <Attachment fileIdentifier="132421232" fileSize="35544"/>
            </Attachments>
        </Item>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="8398222254" description="SKID, 36.75 X 57">
            <Attachments>
                <Attachment fileIdentifier="130404636" fileSize="49406"/>
            </Attachments>
        </Item>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="8435567553" description="FAB INSTR., SIDE BRACE">
            <Attachments>
                <Attachment fileIdentifier="142071491" fileSize="102438"/>
                <Attachment fileIdentifier="142071490" fileSize="887808"/>
            </Attachments>
        </Item>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="8435567554" description="FAB INSTR., BASE">
            <Attachments>
                <Attachment fileIdentifier="172551083" fileSize="1881600"/>
                <Attachment fileIdentifier="172573685" fileSize="145681"/>
            </Attachments>
        </Item>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="8435567555" description="FAB INSTR., TOP">
            <Attachments>
                <Attachment fileIdentifier="171051100" fileSize="126563"/>
                <Attachment fileIdentifier="171051099" fileSize="1575424"/>
            </Attachments>
        </Item>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="8435602286" description="ASSY INST, RACK WELDMT, 37RU">
            <Attachments>
                <Attachment fileIdentifier="135543730" fileSize="155618"/>
            </Attachments>
        </Item>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="8435602287" description="FAB INST., CORNER POST, LEFT FRONT">
            <Attachments>
                <Attachment fileIdentifier="129272424" fileSize="603648"/>
                <Attachment fileIdentifier="132214666" fileSize="39296"/>
            </Attachments>
        </Item>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="8435602288" description="FAB INST., CORNER POST, RIGHT REAR">
            <Attachments>
                <Attachment fileIdentifier="121115929" fileSize="549888"/>
                <Attachment fileIdentifier="132214667" fileSize="37265"/>
            </Attachments>
        </Item>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="8435602289" description="FAB INST., CORNER POST, RIGHT FRONT">
            <Attachments>
                <Attachment fileIdentifier="129285018" fileSize="604160"/>
                <Attachment fileIdentifier="132214668" fileSize="38840"/>
            </Attachments>
        </Item>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="8435602290" description="FAB INST., CORNER POST, LEFT REAR">
            <Attachments>
                <Attachment fileIdentifier="132214669" fileSize="36957"/>
                <Attachment fileIdentifier="130362337" fileSize="702464"/>
            </Attachments>
        </Item>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="9435567553" description="BRACE, SIDE">
            <BillOfMaterial>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="8172418068" itemQuantity="0.0001" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="0"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="8435567553" itemQuantity="0.0001" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="0"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="0115020040" itemQuantity="11.00" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="1"/>
            </BillOfMaterial>
        </Item>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="9435567554" description="BASE, CABINET FRAME">
            <BillOfMaterial>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="8172418068" itemQuantity="0.0001" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="0"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="8435567554" itemQuantity="0.0001" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="0"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="0115020040" itemQuantity="50.7" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="1"/>
            </BillOfMaterial>
        </Item>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="9435567555" description="TOP, CABINET FRAME">
            <BillOfMaterial>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="8172418068" itemQuantity="0.0001" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="0"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="8435567555" itemQuantity="0.0001" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="0"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="0115020040" itemQuantity="50.7" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="1"/>
            </BillOfMaterial>
        </Item>
        <Item isTopLevel="Yes" itemIdentifier="9435602286" description="WELDMENT, 37RU RACK">
            <BillOfMaterial>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="3070001100" itemQuantity="2.000" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="0"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="3110011100" itemQuantity="2.000" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="0"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="3110011120" itemQuantity="2.000" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="0"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="3150021100" itemQuantity="2.000" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="0"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="3203271000" itemQuantity="2.000" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="0"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="8398222254" itemQuantity="1.0000" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="0"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="8435602286" itemQuantity="0.0001" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="0"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="9435567554" itemQuantity="1" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="1"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="9435567555" itemQuantity="1" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="2"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="9435602287" itemQuantity="1" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="3"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="9435602288" itemQuantity="1" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="4"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="9435602289" itemQuantity="1" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="5"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="9435602290" itemQuantity="1" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="6"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="9435567553" itemQuantity="4" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="8"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="3070031000" itemQuantity="8" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="9"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="3070007006" itemQuantity="8" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="10"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="3070028000" itemQuantity="2" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="11"/>
            </BillOfMaterial>
        </Item>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="9435602287" description="CORNER POST, LEFT FRONT">
            <BillOfMaterial>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="8172418068" itemQuantity="0.0001" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="0"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="8435602287" itemQuantity="0.0001" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="0"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="0115020040" itemQuantity="5.137" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="1"/>
            </BillOfMaterial>
        </Item>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="9435602288" description="CORNER POST, RIGHT REAR">
            <BillOfMaterial>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="8172418068" itemQuantity="0.0001" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="0"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="8435602288" itemQuantity="0.0001" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="0"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="0115020040" itemQuantity="5.137" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="1"/>
            </BillOfMaterial>
        </Item>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="9435602289" description="CORNER POST, RIGHT FRONT">
            <BillOfMaterial>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="8172418068" itemQuantity="0.0001" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="0"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="8435602289" itemQuantity="0.0001" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="0"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="0115020040" itemQuantity="5.137" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="1"/>
            </BillOfMaterial>
        </Item>
        <Item isTopLevel="No" itemIdentifier="9435602290" description="CORNER POST, LEFT REAR">
            <BillOfMaterial>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="8172418068" itemQuantity="0.0001" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="0"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="8435602290" itemQuantity="0.0001" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="0"/>
                <BillOfMaterialItem billOfMaterialItemIdentifier="0115020040" itemQuantity="5.137" proprietarySequenceIdentifier="1"/>
            </BillOfMaterial>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</ProductDataeXchangePackage>
```

Here is one (very rough) attempt at the XSL; only going one BOM level deep:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="ProductDataeXchangePackage/Items/Item[@isTopLevel='Yes']/BillOfMaterial">
        <xsl:for-each select="BillOfMaterialItem">
            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
            <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@billOfMaterialItemIdentifier"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            <!--<xsl:apply-templates/>-->
        </xsl:for-each>       
    </xsl:template>

    <!--
    <xsl:template name="test" match="item">
        <xsl:value-of select="@itemIdentifier"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="@itemIdentifier">
            <xsl:value-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the desired output:

```
0   9435602286
1   3070001100
2   3110011100
3   3110011120
4   3150021100
5   3203271000
6   8398222254
7   8435602286
8   9435567554
9       8172418068
10      8435567554
11      0115020040
12          8151400002
13  9435567555
14      8172418068
15      8435567555
16      0115020040
17          8151400002
18  9435602287
19      8172418068
20      8435602287
21      0115020040
22          8151400002
23  9435602288
24      8172418068
25      8435602288
26      0115020040
27          8151400002
28  9435602289
29      8172418068
30      8435602289
31      0115020040
32          8151400002
33  9435602290
34      8172418068
35      8435602290
36      0115020040
37          8151400002
38  9435567553
39      8172418068
40      8435567553
41      0115020040
42          8151400002
43  3070031000
44  3070007006
45  3070028000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the logic of your output. I would have expected the indent to increase with each level of the BOM hierarchy - which in the given example would look like this:

```
9435602286
    3070001100
    3070007006
    3070028000
    3070031000
    3110011100
    3110011120
    3150021100
    3203271000
    8398222254
    8435602286
    9435567553
        0115020040
            8151400002
        8172418068
        8435567553
    9435567554
        0115020040
            8151400002
        8172418068
        8435567554
    9435567555
        0115020040
            8151400002
        8172418068
        8435567555
    9435602287
        0115020040
            8151400002
        8172418068
        8435602287
    9435602288
        0115020040
            8151400002
        8172418068
        8435602288
    9435602289
        0115020040
            8151400002
        8172418068
        8435602289
    9435602290
        0115020040
            8151400002
        8172418068
        8435602290
```

Which is easy to produce using a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)** to link each item to its components recursively:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="bom" match="Item" use="@itemIdentifier" />

<xsl:template match="/ProductDataeXchangePackage">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Items/Item[@isTopLevel='Yes']"/>   
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item">
    <xsl:param name="indent"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$indent"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="@itemIdentifier"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('bom', BillOfMaterial/BillOfMaterialItem/@billOfMaterialItemIdentifier)">
        <xsl:with-param name="indent" select="concat($indent, '&#9;')"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

> How could the output be sorted by proprietarySequenceIdentifier then
>   by itemIdentifier?

The problem with this request is that `proprietarySequenceIdentifier` is not an attribute of the `Item` itself; it is an attribute of the `BillOfMaterialItem` grandchild of its "parent" `Item`.

*I put "parent" in quotes, because it is not really its parent in the source XML's structure (that's what the original question here is about).*

To solve this, we must make `Item` "reach back" and get the `proprietarySequenceIdentifier` value from the corresponding `BillOfMaterialItem` node:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="item" match="Item" use="@itemIdentifier" />
<xsl:key name="bom-item" match="BillOfMaterialItem" use="@billOfMaterialItemIdentifier" />

<xsl:template match="/ProductDataeXchangePackage">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Items/Item[@isTopLevel='Yes']"> 
        <xsl:sort select="@itemIdentifier" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item">
    <xsl:param name="indent"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$indent"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="@itemIdentifier"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('item', BillOfMaterial/BillOfMaterialItem/@billOfMaterialItemIdentifier)">
        <xsl:with-param name="indent" select="concat($indent, '&#9;')"/>
        <xsl:sort select="key('bom-item', @itemIdentifier)/@proprietarySequenceIdentifier" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:sort select="@itemIdentifier" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!  You are correct, the intended output was to be an incremental indent based on the BOM level starting at level 0; mistake on my end.  What you've indicated is the desired output with respect to the indent, but it's missing an incremented value for each line.  I've attempted to add this by using <xsl:number...>, but cannot seem to get it to work properly.

Comment: "*it's missing an incremented value for each line*" Are you sure you need this? It cannot be produced at the same time as the hierarchical "tree" above - you will have to do it in two passes.

Comment: No, it's not needed.  I was more curious as to how some type of sequence could be tied to the output.

Comment: Follow-up question: How could the output be sorted by proprietarySequenceIdentifier then by itemIdentifier?  I've attempted to incorporate <xsl:sort select=...> with success in other templates, but not through the use of a key; currently at a loss as to how to accomplish this.
I can enter a new question if that's the appropriate route to take.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must add the `xsl:sort` instruction as (the first) child of `xsl: apply-templates` (in both instances). The use of a key is irrelevant to this.

Comment: Adding `<xsl:sort select="BillOfMaterial/BillOfMaterialItem/@proprietarySequenceIdentifier data-type="number" />` as the first element directly after both `<xsl:apply-templates...` elements did not change the output.  This doesn't quite seem right either, attempting to sort the `<Item>` context through its `<BillOfMaterialItem>` grandchildren.  My natural reaction is to attempt to add another template for `<BillOfMaterialItem>`, and apply that template with the sorts needed, but there too I'm having problems.

Comment: @apatto03 I have added what I *think* is the solution to my answer.

Comment: Thank you again!  This is the result that I'm after.